# C++ pointer array not inputing data properly

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am working on a school project in C++.

My issue at the moment is with the 'placePiece' function. I can't seem to get it to properly place the char value for the player into the array that represent the game board, it always seems to assign the 'p' (Player) and 'c' (Computer) values to completely random cells within the game board.

Place piece function:

```
    bool placePiece(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize, int columnSelection, char player)
    {    
            char* pRow = pBoard[columnSelection];
            for (int j = colSize; j >0; j--){
                if(pRow[j] == ' '){
                    pRow[j] = player;
                    return true;
                }
            }

        return false;
    }
```

Print board function:

```
void printBoard(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize){

    for(int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){       //Print the current values of each cell
        char* pRow = pBoard[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < colSize; j++) {
            if(j==0){
            std::cout << "|" << pRow[j] << "|";
            }else{
                std::cout << pRow[j] << "|";
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl<<std::endl;
    }

}
```

int main (To put it all together, there is obviously a lot of missing code to fully complete the project that's not included in here because it has no relevance to the issue at hand.)

```
    int main(){

        srand (time(NULL));

        int32_t connectedPiecesToWin = 0;
        int32_t rowSize = 0;
        int32_t colSize = 0;


        std::cout << "How many connected pieces does it take to win?" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> connectedPiecesToWin;

        rowSize = connectedPiecesToWin + 2;
        colSize = connectedPiecesToWin + 3;

        char** pBoard = NULL;    
        // initialize board
        //Assign first dimension
        pBoard = new char*[rowSize];

        //Assign second dimension
        for(int i = 0; i < rowSize; i++){
            pBoard[i] = new char[colSize];
            char* pRow = pBoard[i];
            for(int j=0;j<colSize;j++){
                pRow[j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        char player = 'p';
        do
        {
            int columnChoice = 0;

            do
            {
                if (player == 'p')
                {
                        printBoard(pBoard, colSize, rowSize);
                        std::cout << "Player's column: ";
                        std::cin >> columnChoice;
                }
                else
                {
                    // computers turn
                    columnChoice = rand() % colSize;
                }
            } while (!placePiece(pBoard, colSize, rowSize, columnChoice, player));

printBoard(pBoard, colSize, rowSize);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: please come up with a more *precise* title

Comment: please clean up your code. Remove all irrelevant code, and build a MVCE (see "how to ask" page). Of course, throw out all the code commented out.

Comment: Remove redundancy from your text. You say, in two consecutive sentences "I am having a few issues". Yes. Keeping things short and precise is one of them. Remove all the "thank you", "if you have time", "please" bullshit.

Comment: rather get one question answer after each other. So ask a question about your "hot spots", as you call it, get an answer, fix it, move on as far as you get, then ask the next, clear, precise, limited, answerable question :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I have revised my question to better fit these requirements. Let me know if it makes better sense now or needs more revision.

Comment: Your placePiece function has an overflow - `for (int j = colSize; j > 0; j--)`. Change to `for (int j = colSize - 1; j >= 0; j--)`

Comment: Thank you for that! changing that small piece of code helped me see what was going on a little better and get everything really figured out to resolve my issue. In case anyone was wondering this is what my placePiece function ends up being to resolve my problem. `bool placePiece(char** pBoard, int colSize, int rowSize, int columnSelection, char player)
{
 for(int i=rowSize-1;i>=0;i--){
  char* pRow = pBoard[i];
    if(pRow[columnSelection] == ' '){
     pRow[columnSelection] = player;
    return true;
  }
 }
 
 return false;
}`